# Create lagged variables from multi-dimensional (panel) data in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have multi-dimensional data where a personal_id can have multiple application_ids, and the application_ids can have up to 22 rows. Application_ids are unique to a personal_id. I need 5 lagged ratios for a given personal_id.

Here's a sample of the data:

| personal_id | application_id | creation_timestamp | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 |
| 14de | 0ae0 | 2023-10-03 14:46:42.378078 | 0.338710 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 |
| 14de | 9672 | 2023-08-30 13:01:55.107695 | 0.290323 |
| 14de | 2500 | 2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397 | 0.203226 |
| 14de | 2500 | 2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397 | 0.203226 |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 |
| 2b33 | 8d85 | 2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777 | 0.000000 |
| 2b33 | 8d85 | 2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777 | 0.000000 |

The output should look like this:

| personal_id | application_id | creation_timestamp | ratio | ratio_lag1 | ratio_lag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 | 0.000000 | nan |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 | 0.000000 | nan |
| 2b33 | 69c0 | 2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008 | 0.057774 | 0.000000 | nan |
| 14de | 0ae0 | 2023-10-03 14:46:42.378078 | 0.338710 | 0.16129 | 0.290323 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 | 0.290323 | 0.203226 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 | 0.290323 | 0.203226 |
| 14de | ac60 | 2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994 | 0.16129 | 0.290323 | 0.203226 |
| 14de | 9672 | 2023-08-30 13:01:55.107695 | 0.290323 | 0.203226 | 0.080645 |
| 14de | 2500 | 2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397 | 0.203226 | 0.080645 | nan |
| 14de | 2500 | 2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397 | 0.203226 | 0.080645 | nan |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 | nan | nan |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 | nan | nan |
| 14de | db26 | 2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828 | 0.080645 | nan | nan |
| 2b33 | 8d85 | 2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777 | 0.000000 | nan | nan |
| 2b33 | 8d85 | 2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777 | 0.000000 | nan | nan |

Comment: not clear to me what you mean by "lagged", "lagged_ratio" etc

Comment: lagged_ratio is the ratio from the previous creation_timestamp. ratio_lag2 is the ratio from two creation_timestamps ago etc.

Comment: Your example is not so clear, but what you want is basically `groupby.shift` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html

Comment: @Alex out of curiosity, why do you keep duplicated rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-process your DataFrame to keep the unique application_ids (with [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)), then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by timestamp and [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) to get the lagged ratio per application_id, finally [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) your values:

```
g = (df.drop_duplicates('application_id').set_index('application_id')
       .sort_values(by=['personal_id', 'creation_timestamp'])
       .groupby('personal_id')['ratio'].shift
     )

N = 5
for i in range(1, N+1):
    df[f'ratio_lag{i}'] = df['application_id'].map(g(i))
```

Output:

```
   personal_id application_id          creation_timestamp     ratio  ratio_lag1  ratio_lag2  ratio_lag3  ratio_lag4  ratio_lag5
0         2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774    0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1         2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774    0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
2         2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774    0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
3         14de           0ae0  2023-10-03 14:46:42.378078  0.338710    0.161290    0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN
4         14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290    0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN
5         14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290    0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN
6         14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290    0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN
7         14de           9672  2023-08-30 13:01:55.107695  0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN
8         14de           2500  2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397  0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
9         14de           2500  2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397  0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
10        14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
11        14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
12        14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
13        2b33           8d85  2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777  0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
14        2b33           8d85  2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777  0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Comment: This code executed fast! I have more than 1 million rows and +100 features, so this was an excellent solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexGünsberg you're welcome. Yes, I purposely reused the `groupby.shift` object so that the grouping is only performed once (`groupby` is a limiting step). You might also try `tmp = pd.concat({f'ratio_lag{i}': g(i) for i in range(1, N+1)}, axis=1) ; df[list(tmp)] = tmp.reindex(df['application_id']).values` to see if this is even faster.

Answer (score 1):

First convert column to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with sorting columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html), last create new columns in [`DataFrameGroupBy.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
df['creation_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['creation_timestamp'])

df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['application_id']).sort_values('creation_timestamp')

N = 5
for i in range(1, N+1):
    df1[f'ratio_lag{i}'] = df1.groupby('personal_id')['ratio'].shift(i)

out = df.merge(df1, how='left')
```

---

```
print (out)
   personal_id application_id         creation_timestamp     ratio  \
0        2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774   
1        2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774   
2        2b33           69c0  2023-11-20 05:32:26.691008  0.057774   
3        14de           0ae0  2023-10-03 14:46:42.378078  0.338710   
4        14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290   
5        14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290   
6        14de           ac60  2023-09-11 15:15:20.924994  0.161290   
7        14de           9672  2023-08-30 13:01:55.107695  0.290323   
8        14de           2500  2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397  0.203226   
9        14de           2500  2023-08-16 15:32:49.080397  0.203226   
10       14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645   
11       14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645   
12       14de           db26  2023-08-01 10:40:48.473828  0.080645   
13       2b33           8d85  2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777  0.000000   
14       2b33           8d85  2023-06-13 08:06:17.106777  0.000000   

    ratio_lag1  ratio_lag2  ratio_lag3  ratio_lag4  ratio_lag5  
0     0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
1     0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
2     0.000000         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
3     0.161290    0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN  
4     0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN  
5     0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN  
6     0.290323    0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN  
7     0.203226    0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN  
8     0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
9     0.080645         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
10         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
11         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
12         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
13         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  
14         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
```